# Is there a way to create a separate bundle file for dependencies in package.json using angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have multiple angular applications that I load in multiple pages. I am trying to minimize bundle download size when I am loading a particular application. I cannot use lazy loading here as I am using multiple angular application, but all of these applications have same dependencies.

When I try `ng build --prod` , it includes the dependency code within main.js bundle, which I don't want. I want to get dependency code bundle separately so that I don't download redundant code when I am navigating through pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
--vendor-chunk=true
```

Or in your angular.json under the configurations option:

```
"vendorChunk": true,
```

From the angular-cli docs for the build command:

```
When using Build Optimizer the vendor chunk will be disabled by default. You can override this with --vendor-chunk=true.
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--build-optimizer-and---vendor-chunk

Comment: yeah... Somehow I forgot this option. Thanks Anton

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck